# Fill div content with array row data, selected by button click - only returning last row

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, onclick

I have stripped my page of all the bells and whistles to try and get this to work - I have 5 buttons and a DIV. The page reads in rows of data from google spreadsheet and populates an array data[].

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['table']});
  var i, j, x, k;
  var data = new Array();
  var headers = new Array();
  var numRows, numCols;

  function onldQuery() {

    var url = 'http://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=xxxxxx&pub=0', query = new google.visualization.Query(url); 
    query.setQuery('SELECT * WHERE B != "" AND V> 0 ORDER BY V DESC LIMIT 20');
    query.send(handleOnldResponse);
  }

  function handleOnldResponse(response) {
    if (response.isError()) {
      alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());

      return;
    }

    numRows = response.getDataTable().getNumberOfRows();
    numCols = response.getDataTable().getNumberOfColumns();

    console.log(numRows);
    for (i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
        headers[j] = response.getDataTable().getColumnLabel(j);
        data[i,j] = response.getDataTable().getValue(i, j);
        console.log(data[i,j]);
      }
    }

    loadData(0);
  }

  function loadData(x) {
    console.log(x);
    console.log(data[x,1]);
    console.log(numCols);

    $('#test_card').html("");

    for (k = 0; k < numCols;k++) {
      $('#test_card').html($('#test_card').html() + data[x,k] + "<br>");
    }
  }

</script>
</head>

<body onload="onldQuery()">
<button id="btn1" onclick="loadData(1);">1</button>
<button id="btn2" onclick="loadData(2);">2</button>
<button id="btn3" onclick="loadData(3);">3</button>
<button id="btn4" onclick="loadData(4);">4</button>
<button id="btn5" onclick="loadData(5);">5</button>

<div id="test_card">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

It loads the data correctly into `data[]` array, based on the console dump, but I cannot work out why it will only load the last line of data from the array when a: loading the page, and b: trying to load a different row into the DIV by clicking on one of the buttons.

Answer (score 2):

try using .append()

```
$('#test_card').append(data[x,k] + "<br>");
```

Comment: On further inspection, I think there may be an issue with how I have initialised and then referred to the data array. On my page it should be a 20x20 array, but apparently JS doesnt recognise 2D arrays. I am investigating on a very basic version of the code and getting the same error - I will report my findings!